Residual variance in SEM
In structural equation modeling, in a path diagram,  the sum of the squares of the estimates (when in standardized units), and the residual variance should sum to 1.
(As in here)
Consider the plot below (with standardized coefficients):

I understand that one should square both 0.48 and -0.12. Is 0.38 involved in the calculation? No matter what I try, the sum does not sum to 1.

Yes, the covariance between X and M has to be taken into account in addition to the squared path coefficients as follows:
Var(Y) = 1 = (.48)^2 + (-.12)^2 + 2(.48)(-.12)(.38) + .80.
This follows from rules of covariance algebra for linear combinations.

Here, https://groups.google.com/g/lavaan/c/dJeMBlPL9_c/m/3UterfKGAgAJ , in the official group of lavaan package, it is said that the R-squared is also affected by the (residual) variance of the explanatory variables. Would you agree? If you agree, then where in your calculation is the (residual) variance of the explanatory variables implied?
